# How to add a python file that includes custom-built function into kaggle notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, helper, kaggle

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../input/helper')
import helper
helper.get_genre_ratings(ratings, movies, ['Romance', 'Sci-Fi'], ['avg_romance_rating', 'avg_scifi_rating'])
```

----> 1 genre_ratings = helper.get_genre_ratings(ratings, movies, ['Romance', 'Sci-Fi'], ['avg_romance_rating', 'avg_scifi_rating'])

```
      2 genre_ratings.head()

AttributeError: module 'helper' has no attribute 'get_genre_ratings'-->
```

Comment: Why are you modifying `sys.path`? And how do you import `helper`?

Comment: then how to import the helper file in my notebook on Kaggle?

Comment: The only import in the code above is from the standard library: `import sys`. Again, how are you importing `helper`?